# Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined after vite update, why?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I have a react/typescript app and before I updated `vite` I had this solution to check either `env` is development or production by this code:

```
function getEnvironment(): "production" | "development" {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    return "production";
  }
  return "development";
}

type EnvUrl = { development: string; production: string };

const API_URL: EnvUrl = {
  development: "http://localhost:5173/api/endpoint",
  production: "https://ingress-url/api/endpoint",
};

export const apiUrl = API_URL[getEnvironment()];
```

But after i updated `vite` to version 3.1.0 I got error when serving production build with following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`.

By `vite` config is:

```
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { resolve } from "path";
import { rollupImportMapPlugin } from "rollup-plugin-import-map";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import { ConfigEnv } from "vite";
import viteCompression from "vite-plugin-compression";
import cssInjectedByJsPlugin from "vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js";
import { viteMockServe } from "vite-plugin-mock";
import { UserConfigExport } from "vitest/config";

const reactUrl = "my-cdn-url/react/18/esm/index.js";
const reactDomUrl = "my-cdn-url/react-dom/18/esm/index.js";

const imports = {
  react: reactUrl,
  "react-dom": reactDomUrl,
};

export default ({ command }: ConfigEnv): UserConfigExport => ({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    terser(),
    cssInjectedByJsPlugin(),
    viteCompression({
      algorithm: "gzip",
    }),
    viteCompression({
      algorithm: "brotliCompress",
    }),
    viteMockServe({
      mockPath: "mock",
      localEnabled: command === "serve",
    }),
    {
      ...rollupImportMapPlugin([{ imports }]),
      enforce: "pre",
      apply: "build",
    },
  ],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/Mikrofrontend.tsx"),
      name: "sokos-attestasjon-frontend",
      formats: ["es"],
      fileName: () => `bundle.js`,
    },
  },
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
    deps: {
      inline: ["@testing-library/user-event"],
    },
  },
});
```

Is there another way to fix the problem or am I missing something in my `vite.config.js` ? If its another solution after upgrade, what the recommended one so my application behave the same as before?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`import.meta.env.MODE`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-variables) to get the mode string:

```js
if (import.meta.env.MODE === "production") {
  return "production";
}
```

Or more simply, use `import.meta.env.PROD` to get a Boolean indicating production mode:

```js
if (import.meta.env.PROD) {
  return "production";
}
```

Comment: I did it but I still get Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined. I think there is some changes in how vite build the production code. When I updated to vite version 3.0.1 and use the code above as you mention, i still get the same error.

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem in StackBlitz?